# How can a title of an article by the side in android

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I'm a begginer in Android and my teacher gave me the task to create this layout, I know how to create the layout that the subheading will be on the top but not on the side [Image for the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1puUl.png)
here's the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lielhanohov.scrollingtext.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
        android:text="@string/article_title"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_heading">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_subheading"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
                android:text="@string/article_subheading"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/line_spacing"
                android:text="@string/Article_text" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you already read this? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#Weight

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ConstraintLayout instead of the LinearLayout and constrain the left of the article to the right of the subheading.

I've also noticed you're using RelativeLayout as the root layout. It is recommended to use ConstraintLayout instead of RelativeLayout as it is helps with creating flatter more performant layouts. A LinearLayout as the root layout is perhaps a better option in this instance however.

For more information on ConstraintLayout see: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/ and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout It can be very powerful especially when creating more complex layouts.